# Javascript - how to replace a sub-string?

Tags: javascript, regex

This is a simple one. I want to replace a sub-string with another sub-string on client-side using Javascript.

Original string is `'original READ ONLY'`

I want to replace the `'READ ONLY'` with `'READ WRITE'`

Any quick answer please? Possibly with a javascript code snippet...

Comment: I am not sure you are being very honest. The question could be a 'no-brainer' but it is the little things that matter when one is implementing some functionality. Esp things to do with string manipulation. I feel Stackoverflow is best suited for such. So please do not prejudice.

Comment: You were asking how to replace a *defined word* in a *defined string*. I can't see any implementation-dependent subtleties in that, it is just straight and dead-simple. No offense, there is nothing wrong with *asking* that kind of questions. It's something wrong with *up-voting* them.

Comment: Your complaint is groundless. The `alt` text on the up arrow image says "This question is useful and clear..." which is a subjective matter. Now, if it said "This question is useful and clear to Ambassador Tomalak..." there might be grounds for your complaint.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`String.replace()` is regexp-based; if you pass in a string as the first argument, the regexp made from it will not include the **‘g’** (global) flag. This option is essential if you want to replace all occurances of the search string (which is usually what you want).

An alternative **non-regexp** idiom for simple global string replace is:

```
function string_replace(haystack, find, sub) {
    return haystack.split(find).join(sub);
}
```

This is preferable where the `find` string may contain characters that have an unwanted special meaning in regexps.

Anyhow, either method is fine for the example in the question.

Answer (score 12):

Good [summary](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp). It is regexp based, if you use regexp notation you can specify the i and g modifiers (case insensitive (i), which will match regardless to case and global (g), which will replace all occurences), if you use string notation it'll get converted to a regex and you wont' be able to specify any modifier.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var str1="Visit Microsoft!";
var str2 = str1.replace(/microsoft/i, "W3Schools"); //Will work, per the i modifier 

var str3 = "original READ ONLY";
var str4 = str3.replace("ONLY", "WRITE"); //Will also work

</script>
```

Comment: str2 = str2.replace(/^Visit/, 'Don't visit');

Comment: bobince's answer is the more correct; this answer implies that passing a string is not the same as the regex, but as bobince indicates, either way it is used as a regex.

Answer (score 3):

```
stringObject.replace(findstring,newstring)
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the regex approach,

newstring = oldstring.replace(/regexforstringtoreplace/, 'new string');

its also worth considering the g and i regex modifiers, these do a global replace (i.e. replaces all occurrences) and makes it case insensitive.

for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var str = "this is a String";

document.write(str.replace(/\s/g, "_"));

would print: this_is_a_string

document.write(str.replace(/s/gi, "f"));

would print "thif if a ftring"

</script>
```