# Update/Add string values based on another string

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

I'm trying to create manual browser cookie emulation using Node.js.

Basically I have two strings, once containing the current cookie and the other containing new or updated values to be added to the cookie. I want to update the old string with the new one by replacing or adding values. How can I achieve this via javascript?

For example:

```
PREF=ID=2191324fe41c6152:FF=0:TM=1320223272:LM=1320223272:S=H6-vdbEpgEzHAknb;
Foo=kfjaofjiof382f3gio;
expires=Fri, 01-Nov-2013 08:41:12 GMT; path=/; HTTPonly;
```

Is updated with

```
PREF=ID=435:FF=2:TM=1320223272:LM=1320223272:S=zzHAknb; Name=23;
expires=Fri, 01-Nov-2013 08:41:12 GMT; path=/; HTTPonly;
```

Returns

```
PREF=ID=435:FF=2:TM=1320223272:LM=1320223272:S=zzHAknb; Name=23;
Foo=kfjaofjiof382f3gio;
expires=Fri, 01-Nov-2013 08:41:12 GMT; path=/; HTTPonly;
```

Comment: Split strings, put data of first in object, overwrite keys with second object, stringify again?

Comment: May I recommend checking out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162153/how-do-i-parse-a-variable-or-multi-value-cookie-in-selenium)?

Answer (score 0):

```
function string_replace(haystack, find, sub) //replaces all occurences of find with sub
 {
    return haystack.split(find).join(sub);
 } 

function string_add(haystack,upgrade){return haystack+upgrade;}
```

I think you can do the rest.

Thanks to **bobnice** of [Javascript - how to replace a sub-string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252924/javascript-how-to-replace-a-sub-string).

Comment: or if you want to replace the values, go with a regex approach.